# Range definido pelo usuario SQL

Tags: sql, data, range

No sql existe alguma forma de definir o range de uma consulta de acordo com o passado pelo usuário ?

**Exemplo**

Quantidade de dias o usuário inserir for 7, e definir como data do cadastro 
dia 07/01/2018,
o banco retornar os cadastro realizados no dia 07/01/2018 a 13/01/2018, ?

Comment: primeiro você tem que informar qual banco você está utilizando, e sim, é possível fazer isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem sim, varias maneiras! Como você anexou a tag SQL, deduzir que esteja usando T-SQL para escrever suas consultas.

Então analisando a questão com exemplo proposto cheguei a...

```
SELECT nomeDaColuna(s)
FROM nomeDaTabela
WHERE ColunaQueContemData 
BETWEEN DataInicial AND CAST(DATEADD(day, 7, DataInicial) AS DATE)
GO
```

Inclusive fiz questão de elabora um exemplo similar a seu para mostrar que funciona:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Script Utilizado:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vendas](
    [ID] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Data] DATE DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    [Valor] MONEY
)
GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vendas]([Valor]) VALUES(12.55)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vendas]([Data], [Valor]) VALUES(DATEADD(day, 2, GETDATE()), 15.99)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vendas]([Data], [Valor]) VALUES(DATEADD(day, 4, GETDATE()), 21.15)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vendas]([Data], [Valor]) VALUES(DATEADD(day, 6, GETDATE()), 85.00)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vendas]([Data], [Valor]) VALUES(DATEADD(day, 7, GETDATE()), 17.99)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vendas]([Data], [Valor]) VALUES(DATEADD(day, 8, GETDATE()), 20)
GO


SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Vendas]
GO


SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Vendas] 
WHERE [Data]
BETWEEN GETDATE()
AND CAST(DATEADD(day, 6, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
GO
```

Usei a Função nativa do T-SQL:

- `GETDATE()` - Retorna a data atual.
- `DATAADD(intervalo da data, quantidade, data que sofre operação)` - Retorna uma data depois de sofrer uma operação. O intervalo da data representa qual parte data sofrerá a operação (day, month, year - para data). O atributo quantidade representa a quantidade de dia, mês ou ano que você deseja ADD (Números Positivos) e Subtrair (Números Negativos).
- `CAST()` - usei para converter DATETIME em DATE. Espero ter ajudado!